# z-index doesn't work normally

Tags: html, z-index

I am trying to create a 'joined DIV effect'. There are two `div`s, one `div` overlaps on an other hiding the top border of the bottom `div` and creating the effect:

The desired effect:

[image]

**Problem:**

[Link](http://estatebulletin.in/test/)

I've got one Div and one ul, 1st one with class "dropdown-toggle" (line 90) the second ul (line 98) with class of "sub-dropdown".(styles are from lines 247-287)

I want to overlap the dropdown toggle div on the sub-dropdown ul

Thanks in Advance

HTML Code:

```
<div class="offset3 span3 head-right">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div class="dropdown-toggle"> <!-- referring div -->
                            <div class="toggle-drop">
                                <div class="uk-flag">&nbsp;</div>
                                <div class="value"> English</div>
                                <div class="dropdown-arrow">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <ul class="sub-dropdown">
                            <li class="german-flag"><a href="#">German</a></li>
                            <li class="french-flag"><a href="#">French</a></li>
                            <li class="indian-flag"><a href="#">Hindi</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>           
            </div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.dropdown-toggle div{
    float: left;
 }
.dropdown-toggle .toggle-drop{
    z-index: 30000;
 }
 li:hover .dropdown-toggle .toggle-drop{
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px;
}
.dropdown-arrow{
   background: url(../img/dropdown-arrow.png) no-repeat center;
   padding-left: 15px;
   opacity: 0.4;
   filter:alpha(opacity=40); /*For IE8 and earlier */
}
li:hover .dropdown-toggle .dropdown-arrow{
opacity: 1.0;
filter:alpha(opacity=100); /*For IE8 and earlier */
}
.sub-dropdown{
    display: block;

    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;

    z-index: 10;

    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px;
}
 li:hover ul.sub-dropdown{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. No one wants to sift through your pages to find the issue. Plus once it's fixed, future visitors won't be able to see the original problem.

Comment: Could you please copy-paste the relevant lines here? That makes answering a question a lot easier.